# Mobile stretches div of screen due to viewwidth

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

Happy New Year's, everyone!

My first question here on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to build a simple blog for myself, and I'm trying my best to make it responsive for most devices. But iPhone 4 is giving me a headache.

For my blog articles, what I envision is that the first thing the user sees is a `div` that has a height of 100vh and width of 100vw, containing an image and the title of a blog article, like this:

[image]

I close that `div`, called "Headline", and open a new one called "Content" where I want the actual blog text to be.

I've tested my site on laptop, iPad, iPhone 6, 5, and 4. The latter is giving me a headache. As soon as as I add any formatting to the "Content" `div`, the previous `div`, "Headline", gets stretched way past 100vh, so you have to scroll very far down before the article text begins. What's even more confusing is that the error seems inconsistent. Reloading the page gives me different results, and sometimes, if I refresh it often enough, it occasionally appears as intended. Here's an example of what it sometimes looks like:

[image]

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would love some help. Here is the HTML and CSS that I think is relevant, please let me know if you need more information.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

html, html a {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
}

html {
}

body {
}

a {color: inherit;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}

#namelogo p {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

#namelogo a {
    font-size: 3rem;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#namelogo a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #fff;
}

#headline {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#layer {
    min-height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

#vertical-align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-52%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-52%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-52%);
    transform: translateY(-52%);
    width: 100%;
}

.posttitle {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 90%;
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
}

.postinfo {
    padding-top: 1.3rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#content {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content h1 {
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: #353535;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    line-height: 3.4rem;
    padding-top: 8rem;
    padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

#content h2 {
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

#content p {
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: #353535;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Crimson+Text:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="headline" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449710146567-1e282fa41f2f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=c1bffcef22907f217af2fdbc3e430855);">
        <div id="layer" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)">
            <div id="namelogo">
                <p><a href="../index.html">Peter Dam</a></p>
            </div>
                <div id="vertical-align">
                    <h1 class="posttitle">Why the Unfamiliar is Frightening and Why You Should Face It Anyway</h1>
                    <p class="postinfo">January 4, 2016 &bull; 13 minute read &bull; by Peter Dam</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <h1>I have never done this before. My decision to pursue a future as a writer came as a surprise to myself. When I tell people about it—especially that it will revolve around a blog—I typically receive a sympathetic, concerned smile. A smile that tells me they think it's an appealing ambition, but also naïve.</h1>
            <p>
I often find myself procrastinating and postponing the act of sitting down to write. My mind is mostly on how much better the other writers are, and I feel hesitant to begin. Instead, I convince myself that it's more logical to finish designing my website first, or to read an article about how to write well.
<br><br>    </p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p> &#169; 2016 Peter Dam. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you have the  `#headline`  have a `height: 100vh` instead of `min-height:100vh`  ?

Comment: This sounded like it would solve the problem, but unfortunately, it persists. The phone shows the intended render for half a second, and then it stretches out right after that. Still feeling puzzled

Answer (score 0):

So since not all browsers interpret our code the same way, and even worst some don't even  have some of the **newer** properties in this case `Viewport H/W` i.e `vh/vw`, it is sometimes a good idea to have a fallback for some of these browsers so maybe setting this would help, hope it helps.

And also, I dont know if it is your intention to have the `headline` be of `min-height` meaning it **could** be *taller*  so what happens if you also try to set its `height: 100vh` instead.

```
body{
height:100%; 
width: 100%
}

#headline{
height: 100%;
height: 100vw;
/* rest of your code . . . */
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border: none;
    font-weight: normal; 
}

html, html a {
    font-size: 10px; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
} 

html {
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

a {color: inherit;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}

#namelogo p {
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;    
}

#namelogo a {
    font-size: 3rem;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#namelogo a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #fff;
}

#headline {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#layer {
    min-height: inherit;
    width: inherit;    
}

#vertical-align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52%;        
    -moz-transform: translateY(-52%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-52%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-52%);
    transform: translateY(-52%);
    width: 100%;
}

.posttitle {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 90%; 
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
}

.postinfo {
    padding-top: 1.3rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#content {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content h1 {
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: #353535;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    line-height: 3.4rem;
    padding-top: 8rem;
    padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

#content h2 {
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

#content p {
    font-family: "Crimson Text", "Georgia", serif;
    color: #353535;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Crimson+Text:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="headline" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449710146567-1e282fa41f2f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=c1bffcef22907f217af2fdbc3e430855);">
        <div id="layer" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4)">  
            <div id="namelogo">
                <p><a href="../index.html">Peter Dam</a></p>
            </div>
                <div id="vertical-align">
                    <h1 class="posttitle">Why the Unfamiliar is Frightening and Why You Should Face It Anyway</h1>
                    <p class="postinfo">January 4, 2016 &bull; 13 minute read &bull; by Peter Dam</p>    
                </div>            
        </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="content">
            <h1>I have never done this before. My decision to pursue a future as a writer came as a surprise to myself. When I tell people about it—especially that it will revolve around a blog—I typically receive a sympathetic, concerned smile. A smile that tells me they think it's an appealing ambition, but also naïve.</h1>
            <p>
I often find myself procrastinating and postponing the act of sitting down to write. My mind is mostly on how much better the other writers are, and I feel hesitant to begin. Instead, I convince myself that it's more logical to finish designing my website first, or to read an article about how to write well.
<br><br>    </p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p> &#169; 2016 Peter Dam. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: This sounded like it would solve the problem, but unfortunately, it persists. The phone shows the intended render for half a second, and then it stretches out right after that. Changing it to max-height didn't solve the issue, either. Still feeling puzzled!

Comment: Do you have Javascript in your page ? try setting the properties with `!important`   like this:  `height: 100vh!important`

Comment: I don't have javascript yet. I tried it anyway, but it didn't help. I'm really lost, this kind of design that I'm going for should be so simple, and so is the skeleton upon which it is built.